# How to compute inequality that involves logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I was reading a math book and I faced with expression I could not solve. Well, I even do not know how to begin, really. I understand that in order to compute power we need to find a logarithm. But... this problem mess everything in my head. Here is the expression and its solution. I would be really happy for detailed steps of how this computation is done. Thank you!

$$1-\left(\dfrac{35}{36} \right)^n \geq \dfrac{1}{2}$$
$$n \geq \dfrac {\ln (\dfrac{1}{2})}{\ln (\dfrac{35}{36})} \approx 24.6$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1 - (\frac{35}{36})^n \geq \frac{1}{2} \Longleftrightarrow - (\frac{35}{36})^n \geq -\frac{1}{2} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{2} \geq (\frac{35}{36})^n \Longleftrightarrow \ln{\frac{1}{2}} \geq \ln {(\frac{35}{36})^n}$$

$$ \ln{\frac{1}{2}} \geq n\ln {(\frac{35}{36})} $$

Now, $\ln {(\frac{35}{36})}$ is negative, so dividing it out and flipping the inequality due to dividing by a negative, we have the desired result.

Note that I used the identity $\ln a^b = b\ln a$.

Comment: what about "$\Longleftarrow$"?

Comment: @anderstood That would also be valid.

Comment: Yes but as it is, you don't prove that the first and last expressions are equivalent, and I don't see why you just considered the direct case "$\Longrightarrow$.

Comment: I interpreted the first as given in the question and the $\implies$ was used merely for simplifying formatting. I can use a double arrow if it will make you happy.

Comment: It does not make me happy or unhappy. It is important to keep in mind that these signs have meanings and are not just comas. There is a difference between finding _potential_ solutions and _actual_ solutions.

Comment: The ambiguity in the way you questioned my answer confused me initially. In the future you might want to say something more clear like "you should make your implications biconditional". I honestly thought you were confused about my answer and not just "unhappy" with the formatting. But sure, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: No pb. I'll try to be less ambiguous too. I just wanted to draw attention on the importance of $\Longleftrightarrow$, $\Longrightarrow$ and $\Longleftarrow$! ;)